# SharePoint Online uses incorrect icons in add-in with custom ribbon action

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have recently noticed that the icons shown in a custom ribbon action are incorrect. It appears the icon shown is the `Image32by32` icon (instead of the `Image16by16` icon) but it has the width and height both set to 16.

The classic view does not show this incorrect behavior. It only affects the Modern view.

Has anyone else observed this behavior?